# Find a String in any uppercase lowercase combination and replace it?

Tags: php

I have to replace `STYLE` with `blank` in a String.

But the `STYLE` String can be `STyLE` `STYle` or any uppercase lowercase combination.

I cannot uppercase,lowercase the original string. I just need to find this `STYLE` String and remove it.

How can i possibly do it.

Comment: `str_ireplace` or `preg_replace` to the rescue?

Comment: I just used replace function and tried str_replace but not sure what to put in the search parameter

Comment: yeah  _str_ireplace_ to the rescue.

Comment: @sushilbharwani This question doesn't show a lot of effort and you don't even used google like: `PHP replace string case-insensitive` <- And done! First result 0.034ms

Comment: @Rizier123 one thing that most people don't understand is people from non English speaking countries may not know how to put their words to explain the concern like here you using case-insensitive. I used different terms for the same and didn't see any result. I used words like string with uppercase lowercase combination letters. your thoughts

Comment: @sushilbharwani Switzerland is also not a English speaking country :) But ^ for such things we need branches, means the same question just written differently like yours. So your question will help other people which would write it the same way to find the solution here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str_ireplace()`is ment for this:-

```
<?php

$string = 'But the STYLE String can be STyLE STYle or any uppercase lowercase combination.';

$data = str_ireplace('STYLE','',$string);
echo $data;

?>
```

OUTPUT:- http://prntscr.com/7buhtm

NOTE:- it will search `STYLE` word in a case insensitive manner and replace all of them. thanks.

Comment: thanks:):). if it solves your problem. mark it as an answer so that other can get help.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the case insensitive version of str_replace: str_ireplace

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php